# Python-Generic method to find child of a webelement

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I trying to create a generic method in python to find the child element of a webelement using any locator strategy. Currently I have the below code, please help in completing the method getchildobject in below code. This method should be capable of find the child of the webelement with any locator like xpath, css or id etc

```
getelement="xpath=//div[@id='test']"
def get_webelement_Cus(locator):

    strategy=locator.split("=")[0]
    locator=locator.replace(locator.split("=")[0]+"=","")
    if strategy.uppercase()=='XPATH':
        return driver.find_elements_by_xpath(locator)
    elif strategy.uppercase()=='CSS': 
        return  driver.find_element_by_css_selector(locator)
    else:
        return None


def getchildobject(webelement,locator):
    webelement.????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're searching for `find_element()`/`find_elements()` method which is already created and available via built-ins. You can use it as below:

```
getelement = "xpath", "//div[@id='test']"
element = driver.find_elements(*getelement)
```

You can also do `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` and use attributes of `By` class:

```
getelement = By.XPATH, "//div[@id='test']"
getelement = By.TAG_NAME, "div"
getelement = By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#test"
...
```

In the same way you can find child elements:

```
getelement = "xpath", "//div[@id='test']"
childelement = "xpath", ".//div[@id='child id']"
element = driver.find_elements(*getelement)
child = element.find_elements(*childelemen)
```

P.S. note that to locate child/descendant element by XPath you need to add dot at the beggining of expression to point on current context (`".//tag_name"`)

Comment: `getelement` is a tuple of `strategy` and `locator`. `*getelement` means extract those two values from `getelement`

Comment: that's an awesome solution. It worked for me. Thanks @Andersson